# Is there any way of removing (or unflagging) all of a user's flags?

Tags: rules, flags

I have a situation where a privileged user (role that is purchased) can flag content and receive email notifications to comments posted. When the role is expired, I need for them to stop receiving these emails. Is there any way (possibly using rules) to unflag all of the content they have flagged? Or is there another approach I should be taking?

Comment: Are you deleting the user when a selected role is expired.

Comment: User account remains, just the premium role they paid for is removed.

Comment: please check if the following reply works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out the event for expiring the roles, there you can unset the flag programmatically. However with other approach you can also add a check the role of user you are sending email to.

Here goes the steps:

- Install [rules_conditional](https://drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module. This module allows to add
  extra conditions inside the rules action.
- Please check the screen shots. [image]

Configurations as in following screenshot.
[image]

**Remember to have the nesting structure as in screenshot.**